# Sum and average of unknown inputs and return the results when input is a string like "done". Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function NumCalc which reads values typed in by the user. When the user enters “done” the function should report back the sum and average of the previous values.
One of my assignments.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Daniel welcome to StackOverflow, you can only get help if you add details of how you're approaching your assignment question.

Comment: "One of my assignments" - yes, one of _your_ assignments, not ours. Please show what you've tried and where exactly you're having issues.

Comment: def numCalc():
    print("Insert numbers to calculate their sum and average.")
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    number = int(input())

    while number != 0:
        number = int(input())
        sum = sum + number
        count += 1
    if count == 0:
        print("Insert some numbers")
    if number == str("done"):
        print("Sum:",sum,)
        print("Average:",sum/count)

Comment: This is what I've tried but I think a while would be better. I don't know how to make the program with an unlimited amount of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I did it at last:

```
def numCalc():
print("Insert numbers to calculate their sum and average.")
count = 0
sum = 0
myNumber = input()

while myNumber != "done":
    sum = sum + int(myNumber)
    count += 1
    myNumber = input()
print(sum, sum/count)
```